# How to format data which I obtain from two tables using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get data from two tables. I have patient names and ID in one table and appointment time in other table.

```
Table1:
Name Id
Joe Wang 1234
Jack Steward 5555

Table2:
Id     Month Date
1234   Jan   15
1234   Jan   18
1234   Feb   5
1234   Mar   1
1234   Mar   3
5555   Jan   3
5555   Apr   4
5555   Apr   12
```

...

I get data:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Name, 
            Table1.Id, 
            Month, 
            Date
            FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 
            WHERE Table1.Id=Table2.Id");
```

How can I get the output like:

```
Joe Wang
1234
    Jan
        15
        18
    Feb
        5
    Mar
        1
        3
Jack Steward
5555
   Jan
        3
```

...

I use the following php code and it will least one name, ID, Month multiple times,

```
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
printf("\t<p>Name: %s Id: %s %s %s</p>\n",
    htmlspecialchars( $row["Name"] ),
    htmlspecialchars( $row["Id"] ),
            htmlspecialchars( $row["Month"] ),
    htmlspecialchars( $row["Date"] )
    );
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you use a loop, as you are, then keep track of each "column" and only output a new column header when it changes. No, we won't write that for you. That's your job. Write something, then we'll try to help fix it.

Comment: Create 3d array using `[$id][$month][] = $date;`

Comment: The actual dataset is larger with more items. I cannot simply use a 3d array. May I ask how to keep track of each "column"?

Answer (score 0):

The first column that matters for grouping is `Id`. So you do your master array on it, and for each different id, set the name once. The second grouping column is `Month`, so you must make one array for each of them within the loop on ids, and create an entry for each date.

To help you out in this task, I suggest:

- adding an `ORDER BY Id, Month` clause in your query,
- do a `var_dump` of the array after it's been constructed to compare its structure with the desired result.